# How does one make an auto-sized HTML canvas on a page with an auto-sized footer?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, canvas

My problem is demonstrated in the following jsfiddle. It works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox:
https://jsfiddle.net/m0u175o8/1/

There should be no pink showing up on the right side, the area above the footer should be black (canvas).

I've got a footer at the bottom of the page. The height of the footer needs to be determined dynamically based on its contents. Above it sits a canvas that should take up the remaining portion of the screen. There are a couple of other panes like a header and a side bar. I included them in the jsfiddle but I'm not sure they have effect on the problem.

In actuality, the contents of my panes are laid out using bootstrap 3 so the jsfiddle imports bootstrap.

For reference, here is the HTML:

```
<div class="header">header<div>
<div class="left-pane">scrollable</div>
<div class="right-pane">
  <div class="canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-pane">dynamic <br> height <br> footer</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}

.left-pane {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: -75%;
  height: 200vw;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 101;
}

.right-pane {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  float: left;
  z-index: 100;
  display: table;
  background-color: pink;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}

.bottom-pane {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: table-row;
}

canvas {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I didn't dig into the problem between chrome and FF, but are you sure you want the chrome version ? https://jsfiddle.net/m0u175o8/2/  My advice : Don't use css to resize your canvas element.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the feedback. I already had a JS window resize listener that would update the aspect ratio of the graphics.

What I ended up doing is adding the canvas directly to the body as "position: fixed" and had the resize listener update the canvas bounds to match the bounds of the "canvas-wrapper" div.